Why doesn't web3 gun library work well together with Angular v18.2?
I'm trying to incorporate gun web3 library into my Angular app, but I'm running into the following error:

[vite] Internal server error: Cannot find module './lib/text-encoding'
Require stack:

I'm using Angular v18.2 so Vite is incorporated into the pipeline, but it is not included in package.json nor the tsconfig.json nor the angular.json.
Everyting seemed to work fine until I decided to move my login logic into seperate component from the main app.component.ts
I generated a new component, moved my logic there and the error popped. These are my imports from the new component with login:
The developer seems to give a sort of solution to this problem (https://gun.eco/docs/Vite), but it requires a change too be made inside
vite.config.js which is not available in Angular v18.2.
This is entire login-page.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PinataSDK } from "pinata-web3";
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MetaMaskSDK } from "@metamask/sdk";
import Gun from 'gun';
import 'gun/sea';
import { LoggedUserDataService } from '../../../resources/LoggedUserDataService/logged-user-data.service';
import { env } from '../../../env';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login-page.component.scss'
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit{

  MetaMaskSDK : any;
  PinataSDK : any;
  UserAccount : any;

  title : string = "STF";
  accountConnected : boolean = false;
  loginNeeded : boolean = false;
  registerNeeded : boolean = false;
  myForm: FormGroup;
  routerAN : any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.PinataSDK = new PinataSDK({
        pinataJwt: env.JWT,
        pinataGateway: "brown-faithful-shrimp-92.mypinata.cloud",
      });
  
      const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK({
        dappMetadata: {
          name: "STF",
          url: window.location.href,
        },
        infuraAPIKey: env.INFURA_API_KEY,
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        MMSDK.init().then(() => {
          this.MetaMaskSDK = MMSDK.getProvider();   
        });
      }, 0);
    }

    
  constructor(private fb : FormBuilder, private router1 : Router, private loggeduserData : LoggedUserDataService){
      this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        password: ['']
      });
      this.routerAN = router1;
    }

  async ConnectMetaMask(){
    await this.MetaMaskSDK.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }).then((accounts : any) => {    
      this.UserAccount = accounts[0];
    });

    if(this.UserAccount != null){
      const gun = Gun();
      this.accountConnected = true;

      gun.get(`~@${this.UserAccount + "STF"}`).once(data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {
          this.loginNeeded = true;
        } else {
          this.registerNeeded = true;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  async Login(){
    const gun = Gun();
    const user = gun.user();
    const SEA = Gun.SEA;
    
    if(this.loginNeeded){
      user.auth(this.UserAccount + "STF", this.myForm.get('password')?.value, (ack) =>{
        if ('err' in ack) {
          // Niepoprawne hasło
        } else {
          console.log("zalogowano");
          this.loggeduserData.loggedUserWalletAddress = this.UserAccount;
          this.loggeduserData.loggedUserWalletAddressSTF = this.UserAccount + "STF";
          this.routerAN.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
      });
    }
    else{
      user.create(this.UserAccount + "STF", this.myForm.get('password')?.value, ack => {
        if (ack) {
          console.log('Error:', ack);
        } else {
          console.log('User created successfully:', ack);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

Error occurs when I try to open the application after running ng serve on it.
These are all the errors I'm getting:
    [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /@fs/C:/Users/aethi/source/repos/SpaceTradeFedeartion/STF_UI/.angular/cache/18.2.12/SpaceTradeFederationUI/vite/deps_ssr/gun_sea.js?v=7542137e:
    |- Error: Cannot find module './lib/text-encoding'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LIXJWMGQ.js
        at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
        at USE (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:14:22)
        at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:237:15)
        at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:15:11)
        at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:259:9)
        at node_modules/gun/sea.js (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:1947:7)
        at Module.__require2 (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LIXJWMGQ.js:56:50)
    
    17:09:49 [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /main.server.mjs:
    |- Error: Cannot find module './lib/text-encoding'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LIXJWMGQ.js
        at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
        at USE (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:14:22)
        at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:237:15)
        at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:15:11)
        at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:259:9)
        at node_modules/gun/sea.js (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:1947:7)
        at Module.__require2 (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LIXJWMGQ.js:56:50)
    
    17:09:49 [vite] Internal server error: Cannot find module './lib/text-encoding'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LIXJWMGQ.js
          at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:15)
          at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:27)
          at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
          at Module.require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
          at USE (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:14:22)
          at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:237:15)
          at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:15:11)
          at eval (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:259:9)
          at node_modules/gun/sea.js (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-5BFEBUKD.js:1947:7)
          at Module.__require2 (C:\Users\aethi\source\repos\SpaceTradeFedeartion\STF_UI\.angular\cache\18.2.12\SpaceTradeFederationUI\vite\deps_ssr\chunk-LIXJWMGQ.js:56:50)

This is the version of gun: "gun": "^0.2020.1240",
Using npm ci only gave me a new error in login-page constructor :
No suitable injection token for parameter 'router' of class 'LoginPageComponent'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.(-992003)
login-page.component.ts(54, 58): This type does not have a value, so it cannot be used as injection token.

Hi, I have tried to reproduce this but its working fine - installed Angular v18.2.12 app, installing gun npm install gun - created new component & copied your code. Can you add any more details?

Hi @JamesP yes, I can add more details. This is the error message of one of the errors (all of them are missing ./lib/text-encoding):

[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /@fs/C:/Users/aethi/source/repos/SpaceTradeFedeartion/STF_UI/.angular/cache/18.2.12/SpaceTradeFederationUI/vite/deps_ssr/gun_sea.js?v=7542137e:
|- Error: Cannot find module './lib/text-encoding'
Require stack:


Exactly, when I try to open application after ng serve

OK, sorry but will require Minimal, Reproducible Example to look in to this further.

@JamesP I added more info to the question. Thank you for looking into it in advance

What version of gun do you have in package.json and have you tries npm ci?

That error has noting to do with gun or vite?

It does. Error message clearly states [vite]

no the @Inject error

To anyone who will be met with similar issue - I sort of "solved" it by rewriting the system from scratch as @JamesP wrote he did and it worked. Maybe due to having a lot of dependencies installed some of them were in confilt with each other I'm not sure.
Thanks @JamesP for help!
